# How to find a word that has surrounded with indicator? javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string below which has some identifier to get an specific word on it.

string example: "I will c#hec*k on it"

> the "#" indicates starting, and the "*" indicates for last.

I want to get two strings.

1. check - the whole word that has "#" and "*" on it.
2. hec - string that was surrounded.

I have started to use the below code, but it seems does not work.

```
sentence.split('#').pop().split('*')[0];
```

Somebody knows how to do it. would appreciate it thanks

Comment: You're trying to return 'hec' from the above example given?

Comment: @prettyInPink yes from example string above "I will c#hec*k on it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = "I will c#hec*k on it"
console.log(s.match(/(?<=#)[^*]*(?=\*)/))  // this will print ["hec"]
console.log(s.match(/\w*#[^*]*\*\w*/).map(s => s.replace(/#(.*)\*/, "$1"))) // this will print ["check"]
```

where:

- `(?<=#)` means "preceded by a `#`"
- `[^*]*` matches zero or more characters that are not a `*`
- `(?=\*)` means "followed by a `*`"
- `\w*` matches zero or more word characters
- `(.*)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (referenced by `$1`) matching any number of any kind of character (except for newlines)

Comment: thanks sir for the helpful answer. I am confused with * and [^*]*, could i ask a favor, to change the indication of the last to "%". instead of "*". This would help also future asker to understand easily.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this with Javascript,
there might be a better approach with `regex` though.

```js
let sentence = "I will c#hec*k on it";


sentence.split(" ").forEach(word => {
  if(word.includes("#") && word.includes("*")){
    let betweenChars = word.substring(
        word.lastIndexOf("#") + 1, 
        word.lastIndexOf("*")
      )
    console.log('Between chars: ', betweenChars);
    
    let withoutChars = word.replace(/[#*]/g,"");
    console.log('Without chars: ', withoutChars);
  }
});
```